# PostGreSQL : date_trunc() returns timestamp with timezone when used on date

Tags: postgresql, date, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm doing some tests, I've created the following table :

[image]

When I execute the following request :

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', my_date) FROM  my_table;
```

it returns that :

[image]

I do understand it is a timestamp as stated by the PostGreSQL reference but I don't understand why it add these timezone and why there is that small variation between +01 or +02 ? How are they choosed ? is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're falling victim to `date` beind implicitly cast to `timestamp with thome zone` to enable the function call.

date_trunc is only defined for `timestamp with time zone` and `timestamp` inputs.

`+01` `+02` etc depends on your time locale's daylight saving rules.

if you want timestamp instead of timestamptz cast the date to timestamp first.

```
 SELECT date_trunc('month', cast(my_date as timestamp)) FROM my_table
```

or you can create your own function which takes a date and returns a date.

```
 create or replace function date_trunc(text,date) returns date language sql as
  'select date_trunc($1, $2::timestamp)::date';
```